# dictionary mapping using R

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with two columns and thousands of rows - say column A and column B.

column A is the key and column B is the value.

```
A   B
-----
a1  1
w1  2
ee  3
```

On a user printing `a1, w1` I want to give its equivalent which would be `1, 2`.

Comment: *"on a user printing"* ... this is not clear to me. Do you mean when you type `a1` on the console, you want it to automatically return (print?) `1`? Or is `"a1"` stored in a variable, a vector, or a `data.frame` column, and you want to replace it with `1`?

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary structures are often used to allow for a fast mapping of key to value pairs. Your current structure isn't efficient, and it isn't structured as a key-value pair either. You basically have one object (the data frame) with two objects nested inside it (A and B). To retrieve your value, you're look for the value in one object (A), finding its row (effectively its index position), and then retrieving the index in another object(B).  A better structure for this would be a named vector:
`x = c(a1 = 1, w2 = 2, ee = 3)`. Or even better, use `list2env`.

```
L <- list(a1 = 1, w2 = 2, ee = 3)
e <- list2env(L)
e$a1
# [1] 1
```

This has constant time lookup, which is what you want for a dictionary structure (see below)

Here's how you'd convert your particular structure to an environment:

```
# if df is your data frame
L <- as.list(df$B)
names(L) <- df$A
e <- list2env(L, hash = TRUE)
e$a1
# [1] 1
```

Alternatives for the lookup:

```
with(e, {
< do something>
a1 # maps to 1
})
```

Or

```
attach(e)
a1
# [1] 1
detach(e) # this is the disadvantage here: you have to remember to detach
```

What is going on here? `list2env` is a wrapper to `newenv(hash = TRUE)` if the list has more than 100 elements, so it provides constant time lookup if you need it.

From @r2evans [reference](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/a-quick-benchmark-of-hashtable-implementations-in-r/) in the comments below:

> (`newenv(hash = TRUE)`) is a thin wrapper over a hash table implemented in C, and the performance shows... In R, if you need to store key value pairs, and your keys are always going to be valid R symbols, the built in `new.env(hash=TRUE)` is the clear winner!

Comment: All of these still work: `L$a1`, `with(L, a1)`, and `attach(L);a1` (even though I recommend against the use of `attach`). What is it about `list2env` that adds any value or performance here?

Comment: @r2evans it uses `new.env`, with hash values if the size of the object is > 100. So it has constant time lookup if it needs it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. (https://blog.dominodatalab.com/a-quick-benchmark-of-hashtable-implementations-in-r/ supports with benchmarks and more rationale.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the reference. I'll read it and then add the link

Comment: pretty sure a named vector would have the same semantics,  a scan through name attributes to find an index. Would have to look at the implementation, but 99% sure it's not a hash, but just a vector with attributes

Comment: @jenesaisquoi it's a hash if list is longer than 100 or if you set hash = TRUE. Look at the source code, the benchmarks in the linked reference, or run your own benchmarks and you'll confirm

Comment: I was talking about a named vector as in your first example, eg. `tst <- setNames(1:1000, sample(letters, 1000, TRUE))` which just has an additional attribute, it is not a different data structure

Comment: @jenesaisquoi yes, a named vector isn't hashed. It has to search for its names. It is a different structure, than the OPs (one atomic vector vs. a list of two atomic vectors). The improvement isn't about efficiency of lookup speed, but rather the simplicity of the expression `x["a1"]`. As I said the better structure for lookup speed is the `list2env` generated hash structure.  I upvoted your solution because it works for the OPs current structure, and gave, I think, a good, thoughtful, answer with two examples of better structures for key-value pairs, and instructions for how to create them.

Comment: I mean it could easily be implemented as a hash, as is typical in other languages with similar syntax for named vectors. It would be a nice feature I think for R to have. I think R has awful hash support and it is rarely used outside of environments

Comment: Dictionaries are also used to improve readability, by allowing table lookup with simple syntax. The latter is not addressed by this answer.

Comment: @Wassinger I would say the syntax `e$a1` is readable and simple for users with a basic understanding of R (from object `e`, extract the value of `a1`). This answer is meant to address the specific question in the OP, though, and not be an overview of data structures.

Answer (score 2):

You just want the `%in%` operator, eg.

```
with(dat, B[A %in% c("a1","w1")])
# [1] 1 2
```